# Message from WebsocketAccepter actor goes into deadletter with Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm working on a simple project, which would be able to start PhantomJS processes and communicate with it via WebSockets. I declared manager actor and ws action in my controller:

```
class Application @Inject()(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) extends Controller {

val manager = actorSystem.actorOf(Manager.props, "manager")

def index = Action {
   Ok(views.html.main())
}

def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => WebSocketAccepter.props(out, manager))
}

def start = Action {
    manager ! "START"
    Ok
}
```

Manager actor simply starts PhantomJS, which connects to WS.

Everything works fine, i got opening message from PhantomJS, but next I would like to grab some info from manager and return it to PhantomJS:

```
class WebSocketAccepter(out: ActorRef, manager: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    ...
    def receive = {
        case message: String => {
          val json = Json.parse(message)
          val messageType: String = (json \ "type").as[String]

         messageType match {
         case "OPEN" => {
           (manager ? AskInfo).mapTo[RegInfo].map(info => {
              out ! Json.toJson(info).toString()
           })
         }
    ...
}
```

I pass manager actor as argument, but when I ask info it says:

```
a.a.RepointableActorRef - Message [models.AskInfo$] from Actor[akka://application/temp/$a]
to Actor[akka://application/user/manager#-1822927709] was not delivered.    
[1] dead letters encountered.
```

It's a bit strange, websocket actor goes under temp path. What's the problem?

Comment: Your `manager` actor may have died before receiving `AskInfo`. You can try to add the config `akka.actor.debug.lifecycle = on` for debug

Comment: it doesn't start Manager actor directly, but like this:  a.s.i.StreamSupervisor - started (akka.stream.impl.StreamSupervisor@12b93917) a.a.LocalActorRefProvider$Guardian - now supervising Actor[akka://application/user/manager#-507796102]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by taking out starting process code from ManagerActor to special child actor